# How can i make a piece of code run if a foreach loop has not output any values?

Tags: php, logic

I have an array which I have put into a foreach loop, where each value of the array will be outputted to the user. If the user has entered a search query, the value will be checked againast a regex and only be returned if it matches, otherwise the value is just outputted.

The problem I'm having is I havent been able to figure out how to make a conditional "no results found" output if neither the unconditional or the regex conditional outputs output anything. Code below.

```
foreach ($result as $value)
{
    // check to see if query term is set and if so run regex comparison
    if (isset($pattern))
    {
        if (preg_match("/^$pattern/i", $value)) 
        {
            echo $value;
            echo "<br />";
        }   
    }

    // if query is not set, simply output the value
    else
    {
        echo $value;
        echo "<br />";
    }

    // and if there has been no output for either the regex conditional, or other output,                   
    // I want output "no results". How?
}
```

Comment: Set a variable to `false` initially and then to `true` inside both the conditionals where you print something?

Comment: wtf...Echo no results? Did you even read my question? It's supposed to be a conditional echo. I cant just have it echoing "no results" if the user got results. It's only if there's no output. You're the one who downrated me arent you?

Comment: settle down. Look at your code and think about it for a minute. And no, I didn't downvote you (yet)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I just do my best to make a clear, concise post, only after i've exhausted my other options, and still get random downvotes for what reason i dont know... I'm still not understanding how your suggestion would work though.

Comment: Thanks jon, this should fix it. Upvote. If you want to turn it into a post I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly this is what you need:

```
$found = false;    
foreach ($result as $value)
{
  if (isset($pattern))
  {
    if (preg_match("/^$pattern/i", $value)) 
    {
      $found = true;
      echo $value;
      echo "<br />";
    }   
  }

  // if query is not set, simply output the value
  else
  {
    $found = true;
    echo $value;
    echo "<br />";
  }
}

if($found)
{
  echo "Sorry, nothing found.";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, the boolean flag will perform waaaay better than my dumb output buffering comment.

Answer (score 3):

Before your code snippet add:

```
if(empty($result)) {
  echo 'no results';
} else {
  //the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: This is a good start, but there may be results going into the foreach which get filtered out by the regex which that statement wouldnt account for.

Comment: Ah, I see. That makes sense. I'll edit my answer if nothing comes to me. No time now, but look into output buffering perhaps?

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. Rate up.